# Htaccess causes folder loops

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Htaccess rules on my website:

```
DirectoryIndex /index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)*(([^\.]*)\.)tst\.url [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://tst.url/%3/$1 [L]
ErrorDocument 403 /
```

It's creating deeper cascading loop (from: /foo/bar.php - towards: /foo/foo/.../foo/bar.php when clicking any link).
Links are opening index.php file - instead of bar.php files.
Websites like:
http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/
http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/
don't show any problems.

1. What could be wrong?
2. Is there any non site-affecting way to test htaccess file custom modifications?

Comment: We can't really help you much without seeing your `.htaccess` file. Can you share it please?

Comment: @cyberbit: Post updated, file added. Is there any non site-affecting way to test htaccess file custom modifications?

Comment: What is %3 in the url? and what is your goal?

Comment: %3 is a 3rd chunk of RewriteCond regex. I want to use subdomains on my website.

Comment: What kind of links you use in : `http://foo.tst.url/bar.php` ?

Comment: Because `http://foo.tst.url/bar.php` -> `http://tst.url/foo/bar.php`. If your link is <a href="foo/bar.php"> -> `http://tst.url/foo/foo/bar.php`. Normal !

Comment: @Croises This kind of links:  https://regex101.com/r/xZ6uK1/11 BTW, is there any non site-affecting way to test htaccess custom modifications, or do you know any other place where I could ask about it?

Comment: Not my question. Your link in the page when clicking ?

Comment: @Croises The link is completely different, like `tst.com/another/whatever.php` (while directory `tst.com/another/whatever.php` exists), but it redirects url to `/foo/bar.php`, than after one click `/foo/foo/bar.php` and so on (`/foo/foo/.../foo/bar.php`) and always shows index.php file instead of bar.php, so I don't even know how is that possible.

Comment: Your link is with `http://` or begin with `/` ?

Comment: `%{HTTP_HOST}` is only with the domain name. Not all the url !

Comment: @Croises I'm not sure what you mean, but I want to use links like: `http://www.sub.tst.com/foo/bar.php` in my web browser location bar, but I want to use `/foo/bar.php` inside php code, like: `include('/foo/bar.php')`. Is there any other way to contact you, because stackoverflow has some weird limitations?